# Вход в чат зацикливается

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, мобильное-приложение

При открытии [чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31927378#31927378) и попытке войти (нажатие кнопки join) в Chrome на Android происходит зацикливание обновления страницы:

[image: loop]

[image: version info]

Аналогичное поведение в мобильном приложении SO под Android.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, какой обозреватель вы используете? Проверил в Chrome (52.0.2743.98) на Android (6.0.1) – ошибку не воспроизвести. Под Android 2.2 в стандартном WebView не работает [страница входа](https://stackexchange.com/users/login), но, как я понимаю, WebView на Android ниже 4 версии [официально не поддерживается](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/274323). С мобильным приложением беда :( Отписался ответственным сотрудникам. Как что–то станет известно, сразу же напишу!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил информацию по версиям ПО

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, у меня такое же было на десктопном браузере, с постоянными редиректам, но поправилось в течение нескольких минут, И после обновления страницы с очисткой кэша

Comment: @Grundy очистка кэша не помогла.

Comment: @alexolut, а поведение все еще воспроизводится?

Comment: @Grundy, конечно. Иначе я бы не говорил, что очистка не помогла :)

Comment: @alexolut, тогда странно :-) а если в приватном режиме попробовать?

Comment: @Grundy, в режиме "инкогнито", кстати, не зацикливается. Но SO приложение не умеет этот режим, и встроенное отображение (средствами же Chrome) продолжает за-loop-ливаться.

Comment: @alexolut, так я не понял, все-таки _приложение_ или _chrome_?

Comment: @Grundy и то, и то. Приложение использует движок Chrome для отображения чата. Но можно через приложение выбрать и вариант "открыть в Chrome" явно.

Comment: @alexolut, тогда подозреваю надо как-то очистить кэш движка который используется в самом приложении :-)

Comment: @Grundy меня смущает, что очистка кеша не решила проблему, а приватный режим решил. В чем там может быть дело?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44612/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexolut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось через обсуждение в комментариях, чтобы решить проблему достаточно залогиниться в *SO* средствами браузера *Chrome* (мобильное приложение *SO* для *Android* использует движок *Chrome* для отображения чата). После этого вход в чат работает вроде бы нормально. И даже последующие разлогинивания в браузере не приводят к повторному проявлению ошибки. В процессе поиска решения был очищен кэш браузера, это тоже могло как-то повлиять на решение проблемы.

При открытии ссылки чата в браузере в режиме "Инкогнито" проблема также не проявляется.